# Upload image in jpeg format in multipart file on server in android

Tags: android

hi i am developing an application that needs to post some images in jpeg format to server in multi-part file form , i have written below given code for this but it gives  following response,

```
01-15 00:32:14.119: I/System.out(7598): file is upload {"status":"error","message":"Please, Specify valid Parameter for file"}
```

please someone help me. Thanks in advance .
Here is my activity code

```
public class SendPostActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Context appContext;
    private String messageType;
    HashMap<String, String> fileList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public String finalImagePath = null;
    // number of images to select
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_post);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);

        appContext = this;
        initComponent();
    }

    private void initComponent() {

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLeftNav)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRightNav)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRightNav))
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.send_btn);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLeftNav)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRightNav)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewCamera))
                .setOnClickListener(this);
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewGallery))
                .setOnClickListener(this);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAudioSong)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVedioSong)).setOnClickListener(this);

        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/GeosansLight.ttf");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHeading)).setTypeface(face);
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMessage)).setTypeface(face);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHeading)).setText("Send Post");

    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnLeftNav) {
            this.finish();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnRightNav) {
            String strPostMessage = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMessage))
                    .getEditableText().toString().trim();
            if (strPostMessage.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(appContext, "Type message.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            } else {
                messageType = "text";

            }

        }
        // on this button click i want to post images to server
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.imageviewCamera) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.imageviewGallery) {
            /*
             * Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
             * intent.setType("image/*"); startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
             */
            selectImageFromGallery();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.txtAudioSong) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
            intent.setType("audio/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.txtVedioSong) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
            intent.setType("video/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 4);
        }
    }



    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null,
                    null, null);
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }


    public void selectImageFromGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            new ImageUploadTask().execute();
        }

    }

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            decodeFile(picturePath);

        }
    }

    class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        // private String webAddressToPost = "http://your-website-here.com";

        // private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                SendPostActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Constant.serverUrl
                        + "PostComment");

                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                String file = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
                entity.addPart("file", new StringBody(file));
                entity.addPart(
                        "user_id",
                        new StringBody(Utility.getSharedPreferences(appContext,
                                Constant.USER_ID)));
                entity.addPart(
                        "msg_id",
                        new StringBody(Utility.getSharedPreferences(appContext,
                                Constant.MESSAGE_ID)));
                entity.addPart("type", new StringBody("image"));

                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                        localContext);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

                String sResponse = reader.readLine();
                if (response != null) {
                    finalImagePath = sResponse;
                }
                return sResponse;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // something went wrong. connection with the server error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file uploaded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out
                    .println("file is uploaded ////////////" + finalImagePath);
        }

     } // asyntask class ends 


} // final class ends
```

Here is my server api method:

```
function PostComment()
{
  $obj = new funcs_code();
  $obj->connection();
  $output = "";  
  $uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['user_id']);
  $mid = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['msg_id']);
  $comm = "";
  $type = "text";
  if(isset($_REQUEST['type']))
  {
    $type = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['type']);
  }
  if(isset($_REQUEST['comment']))
  {
    $comm = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['comment']);
  }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_id = '$uid'";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  if(mysql_num_rows($res)==1)
  {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE msg_id = '$mid'";
    $res1 = mysql_query($sql1);
    if(mysql_num_rows($res1)==1)
    { 
      $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1);
      if($row['group_id'] == $row1['groupId'])
      {
          $status = 1; // 1 for comment
          $fileName = "";

          if(isset($_FILES['file']) && is_array($_FILES['file']))
          {
            $allowedExts = array("jpeg", "jpg", "mp3", "mp4", "3gp");
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $extension = end($temp);

            //
            //Check File Extension & Size UPTO 5 MB
            //

            if (( $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg"  || $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mpeg"
            || $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/3gpp" || $_FILES["fiile"]["type"] == "video/mp4" ) && $_FILES["file"]["size"] < 5242880 && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
            {
              if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
              {
                //echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
                $output = array('status' => 'error','message' => $_FILES["file"]["error"]);
                header('content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($output);
                exit;
              }
              else
              {                
                  $fileName = time().".$extension";
                  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/". $fileName);
                  $fileName = '/uploads/'.$fileName; 
              }
            }
            else
            {
               $output = array('status' => 'error','message' => "Invalid_File");
               header('content-type: application/json');
               echo json_encode($output);
               exit;
            }

            if($fileName != '' && $type != 'text')
            {
                $comm = $fileName;
            }

          }

          //
          //Below Condition Used to check, If uploading any media and File not Uploaded
          //
          if($type != 'text' && $fileName == ""){         
               $output = array('status' => 'error','message' => "Please, Specify valid Parameter for file");
               header('content-type: application/json');
               echo json_encode($output);
               exit;
          }

          //
          //In Any Case Comment can not be left blank
          //
          if($comm != "")
          {
              $sq = "INSERT INTO `user_comment`(`user_id`,`msg_id`,`type`,`comment`,`status`) VALUES('$uid','$mid','$type','$comm','$status')";

              if(mysql_query($sq))
                $output = array('status' => 'success','message' => "Comment_Success");
              else
                $output = array('status' => 'error','message' => "Comment_Fail");

          }else{
               $output = array('status' => 'error','message' => "Comment Can not be blank");
               header('content-type: application/json');
               echo json_encode($output);
               exit;
          }
          ///////////////////////////  

      }// group
      else
      {
        //$output = 'user_group not match';
        $output = array('status' => 'error','message' => "User_group_Not_match");
      }
    }
    else
    {
      //$output = 'invalid msg_id';
      $output = array('status' => 'error','message' => "Invalid_Msg_id");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    //$output = "invalid user_id";
    $output = array('status' => 'error','message' => "Invalid_User");
  }
header('content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type is wrong, should be `image/jpeg` in this line:

```
entity.addPart("type", new StringBody("image"));
```

Also, you are sending your `File` as a Base 64 encoded string?? Are you sure the php code handles that? Usually you are supposed to use `FileBody` with the file directly, but you can use a `ContentBody` for byte arrays.

#### Edit

This is how I upload a file with a  `ByteArrayOutputStream`

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
    ContentBody contentPart = new ByteArrayBody(bos.toByteArray(), "image/jpeg", "file.jpg");
    mpEntity.addPart("file", contentPart);
```

This is how you would do it with a `FileBody`

```
File f = ....
mpEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(f));
```

Comment: can You describe your answer please

Answer (score 0):

From your "Server api method"

```
if($type != 'text' && $fileName == ""){         
               $output = array('status' => 'error','message' => "Please, Specify valid Parameter for file");
               header('content-type: application/json');
               echo json_encode($output);
               exit;
          }
```

So that means $type is not equal to 'text' and $fileName is equals to "". So, go to this line:

Change this:

```
  $fileName = time().".$extension";
```

Into this:

```
  $fileName = time().'.'.$extension";
```

Then let me know what happened.